# Nesting If statements for referenced values based on drop-down values

Tags: google-sheets, nested, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to set up an automated value sheet for my TCG collection. I have each ungraded price referenced using value functions tied to HTML tables in other sheets. I then had the thought that I might get some of them graded and added a drop-down column for grades. The prices for graded values are also in these other sheets and updated automatically through the HTML import table. For some reason, when chaining (nesting) the if statements with the value statements, only the initial value reference goes through, the rest presented as false. Below are the functions I'm using.

Below are the functions I'm using

before adding the dropdown:

Price for card: `=value(SSBSP!D21)` where SSBSP is the sheet containing the importhtml table and d21 is the cell that contains the price for the ungraded card.

My attempt at nesting functions to reflect the price for a couple different grades:

```
=if(E3="UG",value(SSBSP!D21),if(E3="7",value(SSBSP!E21),if(E3="8",value(SSBSP!F21))))
```

where
e21 and f21 were the cells that reflected the prices for grade 7 and 8 cards respectively.
This nested function still puts out the correct price for ungraded (UG) cards, but if I change the grade in the corresponding drop-down, it shows as false.

If helpful, I can add the link to view the google sheet as well.

I have a vague idea what apps script is and that it might be what I need to use, but every time I go to check it out, I get a 400 bad request error.

Comment: `If helpful, I can add the link to view the google sheet as well.` Definitely, **so long as** you also include the data as text in the body of the question. There are several ways to add markdown tables, including using the free, online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: In your example, you are referencing row 21 on "SSBSP". How do you know that the data for this card is on Row 21? And, since "SSBSP" gets updated from time to time, do the row numbers also change from time-to-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this formula:
`=if(E3="UG",value(SSBSP!D21),if(E3="7",value(SSBSP!E21),if(E3="8",value(SSBSP!F21))))`

BUT

`only the initial value reference goes through, the rest presented as false.`

The reason is because these arguments are evaluating numbers not strings.

- `E3="7"` - should be `E3=7`
- `E3="8"` - should be `E3=8`

Comment: Bless.   It is working as intended now, TYSM!

Comment: Glad it worked out. You might consider `accepting this answer`: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)